# Using JS .match() to extract number from string, then use the result to test equality

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Hope someone can help as I quite new to JS.  I need to extract a number from 2 strings then test the result for equality against each other.

For example

```
var test1 = "7D"
var test2 = "7H"
```

To extract the numbers I'm using the following code,

```
test1.match(/\d+/) = result in the console is "7",
```

I do the same for the test2 variable and this results in 7 also.

However when I test for equality using

```
test1.match(/\d+/) === test2.match(/\d+/) it evaluates to false.
```

I'm trying to use this condition in an if statement but cannot get it to work, e.g.

```
if(test1.match(/\d+/) === test2.match(/\d+/)){run some code}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to acheive this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match` returns an array. To compare matched value use:

```
var b = (test1.match(/\d+/)[0] === test2.match(/\d+/)[0]);
//=> true
```

[Check this Q&A on how to compare arrays in avascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript)